# Loaded an excel file in Power BI, but it shows null(each and every column) while handling the relationship

Tags: powerbi

I hope u have understood what my prblm is, but still I have mentioned the steps for better understanding

Loaded an excel in BI -> Model ->  Manage relationship -> New -> select tables..and then after selecting a table it shows null

Eg-

| E_no | E_name | E_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | Null |
| Null | Null | Null |

I want to create a relationship between two excel file but one of the file shows null

Any suggestions would be much appreciable!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: are u able to see the non-null values in your data model?

Comment: @Gowtham_7 yup I found something unusual, as u said, after viewing in data model, first 80 rows shows blank and then from row 82 my data starts. But in my excel there is no blanks from top rows, my data starts from row 1. What to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are some pre-existing null and blank values in your file which you won't be able to see in the excel sheet.

Here's what you have to do,

Go to Home > Remove Rows > Remove Blank Rows/ Duplicate rows to delete blank rows. then try to build the relationship.

p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".